# Setting up Cloudfront signed cookies for multiple paths

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

How do you [setup signed cookies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-setting-signed-cookie-custom-policy.html) for multiple separate paths within a Cloudfront distribution?

I've successfully setup signed cookies to authenticate access to the pattern "path1/*" under a distribution, but now I want to setup separate mutually exclusive authenticated access to the pattern "path2/*" under the same distribution so I can grant access to different users.

However, as far as I know, Cloudfront's signed cookies only use one set of three cookies named CloudFront-Policy, CloudFront-Signature, and CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id, so presumably it can only grant access to one location at a time.

Is there any way to support access to multiple locations?

Comment: Have you tried including multiple statements in your policy?

Comment: @kichik [*"You can include only one statement."*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-setting-signed-cookie-custom-policy.html#private-content-custom-policy-statement-cookies)

Answer (score 0):

Use CF signed urls instead! If you have really good reason to use signed cookies, the only possible solution I can think of is to authenticate `parentOf('/path1/', '/path2/')` which is the root (/*).